# touch urls in webview and hold 2,3 seconds to prompt a window

Tags: iphone

I noticed that there are some apps which have the webview, when I touch urls in webview and hold 2,3 seconds, it will prompt a window.
But if I only touch the url but do not hold it, webview will go to the url.

I wonder how I do this.

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't this the default behavior of a web view when you enable links? You can make links clickable by setting the appropriate [`dataDetectorTypes`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950-CH3-SW29).